# How would I go into setting up a firebase project safely?

Tags: reactjs, firebase, react-native, api

I have an app idea which I want to create a working product of. I do have a working demo with React Native and I'm using Firebase for storing documents and images. Creating documents and uploading images to Firebase Storage is all done in the app, but this is just for demo purposes. In reality you would of course want to use an API for storing all that data. At least, I thought so. All I see on the internet is people using Firebase directly in their app. Is this the correct way of doing it? I always learned you should use a backend, for example a REST API for safely handling data.

Is it safe and secure to 'just' use React Native? I want to handle payments in my app, so I really want it to be done securely.

So what's an example of a stack I could use?
Currently using React Native and Firebase. But for safety I'd imagine something like
React Native - frontend
Node Express Server - backend
Firebase - database

I hope someone can give me a little push in the right direction.